# Linux Mint Laptop (With a UPS) Turns Off When Power Goes Out

Tags: power-supply, linux-mint, battery, power, ups

I had a Linux Mint (MATE) laptop with a working battery, but just to be safe I *also* bought a UPS backup, and plugged the laptop into it.  When the power went out, the laptop stayed on, and life was good.

Recently I upgraded my Mint installation, and switched to Cinnamon instead of MATE.  Today the power went out ... and the laptop turned off!

My question is, how could that be?  I certainly don't see any setting under Power Management for "shut the computer off when the power fluctuates", but it seems like there must be one.

Comment: Have you plugged the laptop into the UPS's usb port? (if so, why?)  Also, was it a controlled or immediate shutdown? How old are the UPS and laptop battery?

Comment: It's always the stupidest things ... you win the prize :)  I had disconnected the UPS's USB cable while redoing everything, and forgotten to plug it back in.  Could you please put that in the form of an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Actually, that doesnt make sense ti me!   I would have thought the USB cable would be used to trigger a controlled shutdown - no cable = no ttigger(and would have suggested removing the cable!)

Comment: Well, I don't want to cause another power outage to test it, but I do know that before when I had the USB cable plugged in, the laptop didn't turn off when the power went out ... and today when it did, I didn't have the cable plugged-in.  I'll report back whenever a natural outage happens again.

Comment: Well, I just had it happen again ... with the USB cable plugged in :(

Comment: How old is the UPS and what make/model? Also, wjat make/model laptop?  Im thinking the UPS battery may be stuffed (especially the common lead battery ones batteries die and it might also have a long switchover)

Comment: The battery works fine if I just unplug the laptop (although it doesn't last very long; sometimes it will turn off only a few minutes after I unplug it).  Also, I have my monitor plugged into my UPS, and when the power goes out the monitor stays on.  So it really seems like something specific with the laptop suddenly losing power (or having it fluctuate?) while it's plugged in. And it never used to happen, but I'm not sure if it's the newer Linux OS or some other factor.  The laptop is an MSI GT70 2PC Dominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why your [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/) laptop could turn off when the power goes out, even though it is connected to a UPS, but I'll list a few:

- The UPS may not be providing enough power to the laptop, so make sure the UPS is properly sized for your laptop and that it has enough battery power to keep the laptop running during a power outage including with any other devices that connect to it.
- The UPS may not be properly connected to the laptop, so check the connections between the UPS and the laptop to make sure they are secure.
- The UPS software may not be installed or configured correctly so check that you have the correct software for your UPS installed on your laptop (if applicable) and that it is configured correctly. Or maybe you need to uninstall entirely so it cannot manage the Linux Mint OS if it's applicable that way.
- The UPS could be configured to shut down the computer after a specific time. Check the settings of the UPS software and make sure that this feature is disabled.
- The power management settings of Linux Mint may not be configured correctly. Configure the power managment settings to keep the computer running when the power is off, and also check the settings to make sure that it is configured to work with a UPS.
- The BIOS setting could be set to shut down the computer during power loss, check your BIOS settings and look for the option related to power loss, change it to "`Stay On`" or something equivalent.

Different UPS' have different software and settings. Make sure you check the manual or support website of your specific UPS to find the correct instructions for your device.

Comment: Thanks.  None of these seem to explain my situation, but this seems like the best answer I'm going to get, and may help others, so I'll accept it.